# Perl: Automatically Change a value in table after 1 hour

Tags: perl

Assume a system where the following code works:

```
my $class = DatabaseInterfaceModule->table1->new();
$class->insert( +{ping       => $ping_num,
                  created_at => time,
                  updated_at => time,
                  closed     => 0,} );
$class->commit;
```

It adds information in a new row of table 1 when being called.
I want to make a feature that after 1 hour, closed value changes to 1.
Any modules or hacks?

Ultimately the "DatabaseInterfaceModule" wouldnt matter, DBI, Teng, ... I'm interested in the "automatically add a value or change a value in the table after 1 hour" feature.

Comment: +1 for the anonymous hash constructor `+{..}`

Comment: This could get complicated to implement. For your example case, you could have `closed_at` field, and set it to one hour in future? This would of course mean logic that checks whether an item is closed would need to change.

Comment: mmmm... i see. basically what i wanted to do in perl is what a cron job would do for every row after 1 hour of its creation: alter the "closed" value from 0 to 1

Comment: How about computing the closed field from the created_at or updated_at fields when reading the value?

Comment: then the problem would be translated to how to read the created_at row after 60 minutes have passed from the creation of the row. then its just straigthforward conditional if closed value is 0, change to 1 and commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the wrong question.

If the instance is closed 1 hour after being updated, then the value of the `closed` field is directly derived from the value of the `updated_at` field, and so it shouldn't be a field. It should be a method that's computed from `updated_at`:

```
sub closed { 
    my $self= shift;
    return $self->somehow_get_updated_at + 3600 < time();
}
```

I suspect the real logic of computing close will be more complex than this, but in any case if it is derived from existing values in the table, it should be computed either in the Perl class, or as a field in a view of the DB. Otherwise you have duplicate information in the DB.

Comment: i get what you are saying. so basically in my code, the part" closed     => 0," should become "closed  => _close()," where _close is the private method you have mentioned

Comment: and well somehow_get_updated_at is just a select/grepish method to get the value of updated_at

Comment: `somehow_get_updated_at` is indeed a select on the DB, but unless the logic is more complex than what you describe, `closed` should not be a field in the db.